# CakePHP: No data received

Tags: php, cakephp

I am getting a “No data received” (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) with the following code:

```
/**
 * afterFind - anytime Cake finds an entry in the DB
 * automatically fill in "sendto" field
 * this contains all of the email addresses for the member
 *
 * return @results
*/
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['Member']['id'])) {
            $results[$key]['Member']['sendto'] = $this->getEmailsByMemberId($val['Member']['id']);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

/*
 * Get a list of email addresses for the user
 * For now, return a dummy list
 *
*/
public function getEmailsByMemberId($memberId) {
        $this->contain();

        $member = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $memberId)));
        if(! $member) {
                return false;
        }

        $emails = $member['Member']['email'];

        if(isset($member['Member']['work_email'])) {
                $emails .= ";" . $member['Member']['work_email'];
        }

        return $emails;
}
```

It has to do with the $member = call in getEmailsByMemberID(). If I comment out this line, the code runs without error. Any idea why I'm getting this error? Basically, I want to check the database

Comment: This seems to be a never ending recursive situation. After the `find` you call `getEmailsByMemberId` which does another `find`. Isn't this just an infinite loop of `find`'s? Also, wouldn't the "sendto" be better implemented as a virtual field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AgRizzo told `afterFind` is getting called lots of times. You need to disable `afterFind` callback in `getEmailsByMemberId()` by using `callbacks` key.

> The callbacks key allows you to disable or specify the callbacks that should be run. To disable beforeFind & afterFind callbacks set 'callbacks' => false in your options. You can also set the callbacks option to 'before' or 'after' to enable only the specified callback.

You can read about it here:http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/source-class-Model.html#2926-3004